# A question about genus one string amplitude

Tags: string-theory, supersymmetry, topological-field-theory, calabi-yau

In BCOV's paper http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9309140 the genus one string amplitude of a Calabi-Yau 3-fold was explained in the B-model as the Ray-Singer torsion (there is a similar discussion in the Mirror Symmetry Book chapter 35). Here are my questions.

1. The first step in deriving this equivalence is to see that

$F_1=\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{d\tau}{\tau_2} {\rm Tr} (-1)^F F_L F_R q^{H_L} \overline{q}^{H_R}$

This is an exercise in the Mirror Symmetry Book (exercise 31.1.2). Here

$F_L = F_V + F_A, F_R = F_V - F_A$

where $F_V$, $F_A$ are operators corresponding to the vector and axial $R$-symmetry. However I am a mathematician and don't quite see why this is true. Can anyone explain in more details how to derive the above identity? (I sort of know what path integral and correlation function mean and know the meanings of the operators in the above formula and on which Hilbert space they act.)

2. My real question is that in Landau-Ginzburg B-model, does the above formula still mean something physically interesting? This is why I would like to understand the above formula in the Calabi-Yau case, and to see if the same argument works for LG model. It seems that in deriving the formula for $F_1$ it uses something special for $\sigma$-model.